# The positive zero of the equation $x^n+x^{n-1}+x-1=0$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

The original question follows:

> For any natural number $n$, let $x_n$ be the unique nonnegative zero of the equation $$x^n+x^{n-1}+x-1=0$$
> Show that the sequence $\{x_n\}$ is increasing and converges to $1$.

I proved that the sequence $\{x_n\}$ is increasing:

> Let $f_n(x)=x^n+x^{n-1}+x-1$.
>
> $f'_n(x)=nx^{n-1}+(n-1)x^{n-2}+1 \gt 0$   in interval [0, $\infty$)
> : $f_n(x)$ is increasing
>
> $f_n(1)=1+1+1-1=2\gt0 \space\space \rightarrow x_n \in [0, 1)$
>
> $f_{n+1}(x_n)-f_n(x_n)=\left(x_n^{n+1}+x_n^n+x_n-1\right)-\left(x_n^n+x_n^{n-1}+x_n-1\right)=x_n^{n-1}\left(x_n^2-1\right)<0$
>
> Since $f_n(x_n)=0$,$ \space\space f_{n+1}(x_n) \lt 0$, which informs $x_n<x_{n+1}$.
> Therefore, $x_n$ is increasing.

However, I do not have any ideas for the next questions. Could you please give me
some hints for the convergence of $x_n$? Thanks for your efforts:D